# resizing window without affecting content

Tags: c#, opengl, window

i am trying to add the ability to resize the app window without causing the contents of the window to stretch at the same time. i have tried changing the if statements and tried different ratio calculations to no affect

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        if (mShader != null)
        {
            int uProjectionLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(mShader.ShaderProgramID, "uProjection");
            int windowHeight = ClientRectangle.Height;
            int windowWidth = ClientRectangle.Width;
            if (windowHeight > windowWidth)
            {
                if (windowWidth < 1)
                {
                    windowWidth = 1;
                }
                float ratio = windowWidth / windowHeight;
                Matrix4 projection = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(ratio * 10, ratio * 10, -1, 1);
                GL.UniformMatrix4(uProjectionLocation, true, ref projection);
            }
            else if(windowHeight < windowWidth)
            {
                if (windowHeight < 1)
                {
                    windowHeight = 1;
                }
                float ratio = windowWidth / windowHeight;
                Matrix4 projection = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(ratio * 10, ratio * 10, -1, 1);
                GL.UniformMatrix4(uProjectionLocation, true, ref projection);
            }
        }

        GL.Viewport(this.ClientRectangle);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost,

```
float ratio = windowWidth / windowHeight;
```

most likely doesn't do what you actually had in mind when writing this code. `windowWidth` and `windowHeight` are both of type `int`, so `/` will perform an integer division before the result is converted to `float`. As a result, `ratio` will spend most of its time being exactly 1. And sometimes maybe 0 (if height > width). And occasionally maybe 2 (on some wide screen setups). Most likely, what you want is something more like this:

```
float ratio = (float)windowWidth / (float)windowHeight;
```

Even then, however, as you compute your matrix

```
Matrix4 projection = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(ratio * 10, ratio * 10, -1, 1);
```

you scale both width and height with `ratio`, which means no matter what ratio ends up being, you will end up with a matrix for a square viewport again (since width and height are the same). Most likely, you want to, e.g, scale only the width with the aspect ratio

```
Matrix4 projection = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(ratio * 10, 10, -1, 1);
```

Apart from all that, note how most of the actual functionality is duplicated into both branches of your `if` statement. Also note that you simply skip the case that width and height are equal. You could rewrite this whole bunch of ifs, e.g., like so

```
float ratio = (float)ClientRectangle.Width / (float)Math.Max(ClientRectangle.Height, 1);
Matrix4 projection = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(ratio * 10, 10, -1, 1);
GL.UniformMatrix4(uProjectionLocation, true, ref projection);
```